# Was it ever determined what the "ghost figure" in Three Men and a Baby actually was?

Tags: production-mistakes, three-men-and-a-baby

In the late 80's, there was a theory that there was a ghost on set (and caught on camera) in *Three Men and a Baby*. Was it ever determined what that figure was?

Answer (score 7):

According to the film's wikipedia page:

> The figure is actually a cardboard cutout "standee" of Jack, wearing a tuxedo and top hat, that was left on the set. It was created as part of the storyline, in which he, an actor, appears in a dog food commercial, but this portion was cut from the final version of the film. The standee does show up later in the film, when Jack stands next to it as Sylvia comes to reclaim Mary. Snopes.com contends that the one in the first scene looks smaller from its appearance in the later scene because of the distance and angle of the shot, and because the curtains obscure its outstretched arms. As for the contention that a boy died in the house, all the indoor scenes were shot on a Toronto sound stage, and no kind of residential dwellings were used for interior filming.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Men_and_a_Baby#Urban_legend)

Pretty spooky stuff at a quick glance though haha.